# Dll methods are not invoked on windows server 2008

Tags: vb.net, dll, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

I'm trying to invoke on dll method from an ASP.net web. It's working on a W2003 server but the same dll and the same web is crashing on w2008 server R2 with IIS 7.5.I'm doing like this to import the dll:

```
<DllImport("Cripto.dll")> _
        Public Shared Function DesCipher(ByVal uiMode As Integer, ByVal uiLength As        Integer, ByVal szSourceData As String) As String

End Function
```

I have tried a 64 bits dll compile but the problem remains.

I'm going mad...

Please Help!

Comment: What kind of crash are you seeing?

Comment: It's a Thread Abort crash. Now I have created a new empty one method dll but it's still not working. When I call the public method the web trows a controlled exception because it losts all the session variables¿?¿?¿

Comment: Does the new method have the same signature (argument count, argument types, return type) as this one?

Comment: This is the dll method:<br/>     extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport) char* DesCifrar() { return ("Hello from DLL !\n"); } } And this is the web call: <DllImport("DLL_SGRI.dll")> _ Public Shared Function DesCifrar() As String End Function . I think everything is ok, doesn't it?

Comment: Since VB thinks in Unicode, and a C/C++ `char` value is not Unicode, you should use `<DllImport("DLL_SGRI.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling:=True)>`. Otherwise, the runtime will think the pointer being returned is a pointer to wide characters.

Comment: Thanks David! I'm getting some nice results but I still haven't found the clue of this problem. Now I have changed the type from String to Int and it's working on W2008.                           I have try: DllImport("DLL_SGRI.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling:=True)> but it's not working at all. I think this could be an output type problem as you said, the char* can't be parsed to string. I keep thinking... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the clue.
It is a memory location problem. The main function was returning an array like this:
  char retorno[10000];

The function was declared in the dll code as "char*"

By changing these lines:

```
     ULONG  ulSize = strlen((char*)retorno) + sizeof(char);
     char*  pszReturn = NULL;
     pszReturn = (char*)::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, ulSize);
     strcpy(pszReturn, (char*)retorno);
     return pszReturn;
```

instead of
        return ((char *)retorno)

Now it's working.